# How to get a report for projects created in last 6 months for sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

I didn't find any api query to get the projects list with the project creation date(not last analysys date).

GET api/projects/search

The above query giving only project names but without creation date.

How to get the report for this?
I tried running sql query on postgres database directly but there last analysis date also showing as created_at date and getting multiple records for same project.

Answer (score 0):

On [the official documentation](https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/projects/search) there is the following parameter:

**analyzedBefore**

> Filter the projects for which the last analysis of **all branches are**
> **older than the given date (exclusive)**. Either a date (server timezone)
> or datetime can be provided.

I hope that you can somehow connect projects with branch creation dates and with that create a report. Otherwise, I can't see an option for searching by project creation dates (at least on the official documentation).

Comment: Any suggestion on how to get list of projects without admin users also?

Comment: As i can see, there are no such an option. Try asking here https://community.sonarsource.com/ maybe someone there has an answer